# How to fix memory leak issue in react native component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react native app an their I have created a formik component like this.

```js
    export default class Wizard extends React.Component {
      static Page = ({children, parentState}) => {
        return children(parentState);
      };
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          page: 0,
        };
      }
    
      next = (values) => {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          page: this.state.page + 1,
          values,
        }));
      };
    
      previous = () => {
        this.setState((state) => ({
          page: Math.max(state.page - 1, 0),
        }));
      };
    
      validate = (values) => {
        const activePage = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)[
          this.state.page
        ];
        return activePage.props.validate ? activePage.props.validate(values) : {};
      };
    
      render() {
        const {
          children,
          loading,
          location,
          createpa,
          onpress,
          formList,
          submitted,
        } = this.props;
        const {page} = this.state;
        const {initialValues, enableReinitialize, validationSchema} = this.props;
        const activePage = React.Children.toArray(children)[page];
        const isLastPage = page === React.Children.count(children) - 1;
    
        return (
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            enableReinitialize={validationSchema && !submitted}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
              onpress(values, createpa, location, formList);
              setTimeout(() => {
                formikActions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 500);
            }}>
            {(props) => (
              <>
                {React.cloneElement(activePage, {parentState: {...props}})}
                <View>
                  {page > 0 && (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={styles.sendButton}
                      onPress={() => this.previous()}
                      disabled={loading}>
                      {loading ? (
                        <Image source={spinner} style={styles.bimage} />
                      ) : (
                        <AppText styles={styles.sendButtonText}>
                          {strings('new-patient.pre-btn-text')}
                        </AppText>
                      )}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
                  {!isLastPage && (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={styles.sendButton}
                      onPress={() => this.next()}
                      disabled={loading}>
                      {loading ? (
                        <Image source={spinner} style={styles.bimage} />
                      ) : (
                        <AppText styles={styles.sendButtonText}>
                          {strings('new-patient.next-btn-text')}
                        </AppText>
                      )}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
                  {isLastPage && (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={styles.sendButton}
                      onPress={props.handleSubmit}
                      disabled={loading}>
                      {loading ? (
                        <Image source={spinner} style={styles.bimage} />
                      ) : (
                        <AppText styles={styles.sendButtonText}>
                          {strings('new-patient.btn-text')}
                        </AppText>
                      )}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
                </View>
              </>
            )}
          </Formik>
        );
      }
    }
```

Then I have used this component in another component like this.

```js
const NewPatient = (props) => {
  const {
    navigate,
    onpress,
    loadding,
    createpa,
    location,
    formList,
    group,
    submitted,
  } = props;
  const [intialValue, setInitialValue] = useState({});
  const [validationSchema, setValidationschema] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formList.length !== 0) {
      var intialValues = {};
      for (var groupIndex in formList) {
        for (var fieldIndex in formList[groupIndex].fields) {
          var field = formList[groupIndex].fields[fieldIndex];
          var id = field.fieldInternalName
            ? field.fieldInternalName
            : field.fieldName;
          intialValues[id] = '';
        }
      }
      setInitialValue(intialValues);
    }
  }, [formList, submitted]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formList.length !== 0 && Object.keys(validationSchema).length === 0) {
      setValidationRules(formList, setValidationschema);
    }
  }, [formList, validationSchema, submitted]);

  const isLargeScreen = useIsLargeDevice();

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center'}}
      behavior="padding"
      enabled
      keyboardVerticalOffset={100}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Wizard
          submitted={submitted}
          loading={loadding}
          location={location}
          createpa={createpa}
          onpress={onpress}
          formList={formList}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          initialValues={intialValue}>
          {formList.map((groupDetails, groupIndex) => {
            return (
              <Wizard.Page key={groupIndex}>
                {(formprops) => (
                  <>
                    <SignUpField
                      errors={formprops.erros}
                      fields={formList}
                      group={group}
                      groupIndex={groupIndex}
                      {...formprops}
                    />
                  </>
                )}
              </Wizard.Page>
            );
          })}
        </Wizard>
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default NewPatient;
```

And then I have used this second component in another component like this.

```
const _onPress = async (values, createpatient, location, fields) => {
  var submitObject = {};
  for (var groupIndex in fields) {
    for (var fieldIndex in fields[groupIndex].fields) {
      var field = fields[groupIndex].fields[fieldIndex];
      var id = field.fieldInternalName
        ? field.fieldInternalName
        : field.fieldName;

      field.userInput = values[id];
      fields[groupIndex].fields[fieldIndex] = field;
      if (field.isCommon) {
        submitObject[id] = values[id];
      }
    }
  }
  submitObject['RegistrationFormFields'] = JSON.stringify(fields);
  createpatient(submitObject);
};

const getAllFormFeild = async (getformfiled) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('campaign_Key');
  getformfiled(token);
};

const NewPatient = (props) => {
  let [location, setlocation] = useState(null);
  const [selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup] = useState(0);
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({window, screen});

  const onChange = ({window, screen}) => {
    setDimensions({window, screen});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', onChange);

    return () => {
      Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', onChange);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.formList && !props.loadding) {
      getAllFormFeild(props.getformfiled);
    }
  }, [props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);

    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.createdD) {
      _navigateOnSuccess(props.navigation);
    }
  }, [props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!location) {
      try {
        request(
          Platform.select({
            android: PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            ios: PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE,
          }),
        ).then((res) => {
          if (res === 'granted') {
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
              (position) => {
                setlocation(position);
              },
              (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                Alert.alert('Location permission denied');
              },
              Platform.OS === 'android'
                ? {}
                : {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
            );
          } else {
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Alert.alert('Location permission denied');
      }
    }
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.patientView}>
      {props.loadding ? (
        <View style={styles.spinnerContainer}>
          <Image source={spinner} resizeMode={'center'} />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.patientContainer,
              {height: (dimensions.window.height * 2.9) / 4},
            ]}>
            <AppText styles={styles.patientFormTitle}>
              {strings('new-patient.form-title')}
            </AppText>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              {props.formList && (
                <NewPatientForm
                  group={selectedGroup}
                  numberOfForms={props.formList.length}
                  setSelectedGroup={(value) => setSelectedGroup(value)}
                  navigate={() => _privacyNavigate(props.navigation)}
                  onpress={_onPress}
                  loadding={props.loadding}
                  submitted={props.submitted}
                  createpa={props.createpatient}
                  location={location}
                  formList={props.formList}
                  setGroup={(index) => {
                    selectedGroup(index);
                  }}
                />
              )}
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.hr} />
          <View style={styles.patientBottomContainer}>
            <View style={styles.patientBottomView}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _navigate(props.navigation)}>
                <AppText styles={styles.bottomLinkText}>
                  {strings('new-patient.bottom-link')}
                </AppText>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    mobileNo: state.signin.mobileNo,
    loadding: state.patient.loadding,
    error: state.patient.error,
    createdD: state.patient.createdD,
    submitted: state.patient.submitted,
    formList: state.patient.formList,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    createpatient: (patient) => dispatch(patientActions.createpatient(patient)),
    getformfiled: (token) => dispatch(patientActions.getformfiled(token)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewPatient);
```

After when I submit even though API call is a success or not this is giving me an error like this.

```
 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
        in Formik (at Wizard.js:57)
        in Wizard (at NewPatientForm.js:229)
        in RCTView (at ScrollView.js:1063)
        in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1196)
        in ScrollView (at NewPatientForm.js:228)
        in RCTView (at KeyboardAvoidingView.js:204)
        in KeyboardAvoidingView (at NewPatientForm.js:223)
        in NewPatient (at NewPatient.js:154)
        in RCTView (at NewPatient.js:152)
```

I was trying a lot to find out a solution to this problem from yesterday but I was unable to do so. If someone can help me to solve this issue or giving some clues to check on it is really appreciated. Thank you very musch

Comment: What is on `Wizard.js:L57`? is it the `onpress` or `setTimeout`? I traced `onpress` and trail goes cold at `createpatient` action. What does `createpatient` do?

Comment: @DrewReese 57 line is the starting point of the formik form tag. createpatient  action is what is do the API call it is successfully happens and response also coming correctly when I do a another manipulation using that response in the component also happens correctly but it is giving me this warning.

Comment: I suspect it is something in that `onSubmit` handler causing issue. What steps do you take to reproduce you issue?